# Stack Overflow newsletter lines of text overlap

Tags: bug, status-completed, newsletter

There seems to be a display bug in the Gmail app on Android, using a Galaxy S3.

[image: display bug]

I am not sure, but I think setting header size with `em` will fix it.

Comment: Solution is close: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed as of the next build (happening later today), sorry about the super long delay.